# getEventListener function support for latest puppeteer versions

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

```
const { ElementHandle } = require('puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext');
ElementHandle.prototype.getEventListeners = function () {
    return this._client.send('DOMDebugger.getEventListeners', { objectId: this._remoteObject.objectId });
};
```

In Earlier puppeteer version this code used to work to get all EventListeners. Now it is giving a issue as in version 19 puppeteer has changed the whole directory structure.

So is there a way I can use the similar method.

As I am getting lot of elements using page.$('.my-element')
now I want to get the eventListeners for this element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a patch for the upgraded library. You can create own function.

```
async function getEventListeners(js_obj) {
   let object_id = js_obj.remoteObject().objectId
   let resp = await js_obj.client.send('DOMDebugger.getEventListeners', {objectId: object_id})
   return resp
}


let element_handler = await page.$("*")
let event_listeners_obj = await getEventListeners(element_handler);
let event_listeners = event_listeners_obj.listeners
```